# md chm html преобразовать в xaml для richtextbox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, richtextbox

Ищется инструмент способный преобразовывать md, chm, html в xaml для richtextbox. Пробовал бленд из студии, крайне много телодвижений. Посоветуйте варианты.

Comment: А в чем смысл преобразования в xaml? Почему не работать с RTF?

Comment: Ну rtf то тоже надо откуда то получить, и честно говоря объемный и неудобный формат для поддержки. Если Вордом конвертировать из html в rtf получается нечто гигантского размера, за счёт кодирования нац. символов, да и прочие беды там присутствуют... MarkDown формат был бы идеальным.

Comment: https://github.com/theunrepentantgeek/Markdown.XAML - md в `FlowDocumentScrollViewer` умеет. Может не всё, но мне хватило.

Comment: Спасибо, я его кстати видел мельком, но не очень сообразил как оно работает, сейчас ещё раз гляну по внимательней.